Automatically show diff of file and its swap file in neovim
When I have some work in neovim after it being closed without saving it will be stored in swap file. When I open the same file in neovim I am welcomed with this message:
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name "~/.local/state/nvim/swap//%home%john%thesis.md.swp"
          owned by: john   dated: Thu Sep 19 21:22:40 2024
         file name: ~john/thesis.md
          modified: YES
         user name: john   host name: archlinux
        process ID: 3217406
While opening file "/home/john/thesis.md"
             dated: Thu Sep 19 21:10:56 2024

(1) Another program may be editing the same file.  If this is the case,
    be careful not to end up with two different instances of the same
    file when making changes.  Quit, or continue with caution.
(2) An edit session for this file crashed.
    If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r /home/thesis.md"
    to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
    If you did this already, delete the swap file "/home/john/.local/state/nvim/swap//%home%john%thesis.md.swp"
    to avoid this message.

Swap file "~/.local/state/nvim/swap//%home%john%thesis.md.swp" already exists!
[O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (D)elete it, (Q)uit, (A)bort:

Is there a way to look at diff of swap and the file before choosing if I want to recover it or delete it? It would be great if the diff would show automatically before asking me.

Get a new laptop.

https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15584/how-do-you-view-the-diff-of-a-swap-file-without-quitting-vim , https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/38572/extract-list-of-outstanding-changes-from-vim-swap-file . Found in https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&pws=0&q=vim+%22swap+file%22+difference
